# How can I add UICollectionView in share view?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, share

I’m doing some work on adding a share function in my photo-based app. I’d like to add a collection view in my share function (just like one in the native photo app), but I can’t figure out how to. Share view should be full-screen.

First, I added a viewcontroller with a button named share, and I made a storyboard to be presented modally when clicking a share button. But i think it doesn’t work in a native way. Is there any way to implement programmatically?

Anyone who knows how to implement such function? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Storyboard? Can you provide some more info on your `share view`?

Comment: @Rob oh, i added some extra info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take at look at this [Tutorial by Bradley Johnson on www.raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/975-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started)